# Why would I want to rub my friend's faces?

Tags: miitomo

When I have a mii's attention (whether it's my friend's or my own), I can "rub" their face. When I do so, a bar with text appears at the top of the screen containing the text "They seem to like that!".

But what does that mean exactly? What's the benefit?

Comment: Does this count as one of those "hilarious title" questions? Cause I'm laughing my ass off over here.

Comment: That remembers me of that skyrim question "I killed my wife, what should I do". I laughed so hard when this popped up in the Hot Network Questions.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't mean anything, it's just supposed to be a "cute" interaction. There's no benefit.

Nintendo seems to like that sort of thing, as it appears in games like Tomodachi Life as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's just flair, there are no benefits for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Rubbing a face in Miitomo has no purpose, it is purely a visual effect to make the game feel more immersive.

Comment: "more immersive" - Oh yeah, I rub my friends' faces in real life all the time.

Answer (score -2):

Rubbing your Mii or your friends Mii gives you flowers. They only last a moment though, so don't go running to your gift box.